# Click listener method with passing argument in Android

Tags: android

I'm new to android and Java. I want to make an onClick method which carries an int argument, so this is my attempt:

```
public void randomClick(final int randomIndex)
    {
      private OnClickListener top_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent top = new Intent(Main.this, ProjectDetail.class);
                    top.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position", randomIndex);
                    startActivity(top);
        }
        };
    }
```

but it still contains error, can anybody fix that for me?

Later I want set the method to an ImageView, it will look more or less like this `image1.randomClick(randomIndex1);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently in your implementation the `OnClickListener` is not bounded to any view, so it won't get fired.

You should create your own (might be inner but not anonymous) class implementing the `OnClickListener` interface:

```
public class RandomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private final int randomIndex;

    public RandomClickListener(final int randomIndex)
    {
        this.randomIndex = randomIndex;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent top = new Intent(Main.this, ProjectDetail.class);
        top.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position", randomIndex);
        startActivity(top);
    }
}
[...]
image1.setOnClickListener(new RandomClickListener(randomIndex));
```

This way when you click on the `image1` it will start the `ProjectDetail` activity with the `randomIndex` set above.

If you'd like to explicitly start the `ProjectDetails` activity (without any user interactions such as a click), you don't need an `OnClickListener` at all.

Comment: I'm glad you made it! happy coding further :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed for the app I'm writing. Thanks!